# Calculate average distance between points in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a shapefile containing 28915413 points.

I've obtained this information using the following python script:

```
from osgeo import ogr

# Get a Layer's Extent
inShapefile = "c:/test.shp"
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inShapefile, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()
extent = inLayer.GetExtent()
featureCount = inLayer.GetFeatureCount()


print(extent)
print(featureCount)
```

I'm wondering is there a way to find an average of the spacing between each point using python? I understand there are a lot of points in the dataset

Comment: Is there some order to the points? Or do you need to compare each point to every other point? If the latter, there would be 28915413 * 28915413 computations to perform.

Comment: @grbeazley the data represents bathymetry survey data, so most of the time it should be evenly spaced

Comment: @grbeazley I think that would be `(28915412 * 28915413) / 2` computations, because `28915413 * 28915413` implies that the distance from `a` to `b` and the distance from `b` to `a` are 2 different things and it also includes the distance from every point to itself, but I agree that's still a lot, and maybe too much for python to handle.

Comment: Good point @DavidCamp it would be `/ 2`, the magnitude of the problem is largely the same however. @hello_12039 what structure is the file in, are you able to structure it using any libraries like `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: @grbeazley its in XYZ, so I could read it in with them headings

Comment: would an pretty good estimate suffice? You can estimate pretty well by define a center C, and create say 1000 radius counts, which cover the (min) max distance from C. imaging tower of hanoi.